# Returning to the beginning of a piece of code when if statement condition is not met

Tags: if-statement

I am totally new to programming and I have been trying to get a simple piece of code working. However I keep getting multiple different errors so I assume I am doing something very wrong somewhere along the line... Here is my code at the moment:

```
userName = input('Please enter your name: ')
age = input('Please enter your age: ')

if int(age) <= 5:
    print(userName, 'you are too young to play') break
else:
    print (userName, 'Your old enough')

factor = 2
finalAge = int(age) + int(factor)
multAge = int(age) * int(factor)
divAge = float(age) / int(factor)

print('In', factor, 'years you will be', finalAge, 'years old', userName )
print('Your age multiplied by', factor, 'is', multAge)
print('Your age divided by', factor, 'is', divAge)
```

What I want to do is, if the user's age is not higher than 5, then they get the message that they are too young to play and it returns to the start of the piece of code - asking for the name again.

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a loop.  Syntax depends on language, which you haven't specified.  As pseudo-code, you could do

```
loop indefinitely
    prompt for name and age
    if age is less than 5 
        print error
    otherwise
        print that age is ok
        break loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at while loops. For this you'd be able to set some kind of condition (such as an "old_enough" variable and when that becomes true, the loop stops running.

You would set this value inside the if statement. By default it should be whatever will make the loop run

There's loads of tutorials online for this, but here's an example in python (your code sample looks like Python3):

```
old_enough = False
while not old_enough:
    # do something
    if age > 5:
        print("You're old enough")
        old_enough = True
    else:
        print("you're not old enough")
```

That should make sense. if not, please do look up documentation. It'll be better for you in the long term